# deleting an exist field mvc3 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i have two tables CONSTANTE with NOM AS A FIELD  and RUBRIQUE WITH FORMULE AS A FIELD AND THE FORMULE can contains NOM :for exemple i have 'COM'P AS A NAME AND 'COMP*4*C' as a FORMULE i want to interdict to delet a NOM contained in a FORMULE THERE IS MY CODE BUT it didn't work when using the sql language link :

```
public JsonResult Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest,ConstanteVM vm)
    {  

        try
        { 

            var query = from c in entity.T_RUBRIQUE    
                     where !(from c2 in entityConstante.T_CONSTANTE    
                             where c.FORMULE    
                                 .Contains(c2.NOM)   
                                    select c.T_RUBRIQUE );
                     query.Count();


           if (query==0)
            {
```

ConstanteVM assur = ServiceApplicatif.Delete(vm.ConstanteId);

```
            ViewData["ConstanteType"] = new SelectList(RefDataManager.GetRefData<ConstanteTypeVM>(), "ConstanteTypeCode", "ConstanteTypeLibelle");

            DataCache dataCache = new DataCache(CurrentSecurityContext.TenantID);
            dataCache.DropDataCache<ConstanteVM>();

           }

           return Json(new[] { vm }.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest, ModelState));
        }

        catch 
        { 
            ModelState.AddModelError("NOM", "Doit pas etre supprimé ");
            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }
    }
```

Comment: query is IEnumerable, how can u check if `query==0`. Store count in variable and check it

Comment: okey then my query is it correct?? what namespace i woudl add to reconize query?? and i used entity.name of the table but it didn't reconize it!! @ Nitin Varpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this part, and let me know if this helps.

```
if (query==0)
```

to

```
if (query.Any())
```

Comment: first of all i change my query but i have a problem in the serviceapplicatif its called twice public JsonResult Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest,ConstanteVM vm)
        {try {   List<ConstanteVM> lstVM = ServiceApplicatif.GetListe().OrderBy(x => x.NOM).ToList();
 List<RubriqueVM> RUBVM= ServiceApplicatif.GetListe();
var query = from T_RUBRIQUE in RUBVM  from T_CONSTANTE in lstVM   where T_RUBRIQUE.FORMULE  .Contains(T_CONSTANTE.NOM)  select T_RUBRIQUE.FORMULE;

Comment: it's because query is an object that contains items and not a number, query.Count() could give you a number of items in query. But in your case you only want to know if there are any item at all so .Any() is the best choice I believe.